# How to change encoding of layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-web-client, encoding

After loading a point layer out of a text file (plug in add delimited text layer) saved in ISO 8859-15 (Latin 9) out of Access, I did save the layer under Qgis 1.8 with the ISO 8859-15 encoding.

When going into the properties of the layer, it stays in UTF-8 (layer properties - general - Provider specific options - Encoding). No matter what encoding I set there, after closing and reopening the properties window it still stays in UTF-8.

Encoding seems to be still correct within the desktop Qgis, but when opening the project in the Qgis-web-client, not all special characters are correctly displayed.

Does anybody know a remedy?

Comment: On the mailing list there was talk about some encoding issues in 1.8. It might be worth checking with them if the behavior you describe is covered by the known problem and if it has been fixed in the developer version.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the issue has been fixed in the development build of QGIS.

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/75dc85b4d652116814873bb7674cab15ce6cde66

Installed QGIS version 1.9.0-Master and tried it out, works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm this in python console:

`>>> layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`
`>>> layer.dataProvider().encoding()`
`PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'UTF-8')`

`>>> layer.setProviderEncoding(u'latin9')`
`>>> layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'latin9')`

`>>> layer.dataProvider().encoding()`
`PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'UTF-8')`